# RIGHT JOIN is returning all NULL results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
I'm trying to retrieve fields `name`, `quantity` and `custom_message` from table 1 and join the correct associated field `value` from table 2 - to give me:

```
name | quantity | custom_message | value
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents.name, vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents.quantity,
       vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents.custom_message
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents
RIGHT JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data 
  ON vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents.id = vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data.id
WHERE form_id =2
OR form_id =3
```

which is returning

```
 name | quantity | custom_message
 NULL          NULL       NULL
 NULL          NULL       NULL + 3 more rows of nulls
```

`vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents`:

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWa9y.png)

`vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data`:

[image: table 2]

I just don't know where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct image for the first table? That looks like the output of the query, not the input table.

Comment: Sorry - 2nd image is here http://code11.co.uk/stack-images/Capture2.PNG - trying to retrieve correct 'value' field

Comment: What about the first image?

Comment: Where is the `id` column in the first table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe right join should be inner join. Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    vcc.name,
    vcc.quantity,
    vcc.custom_message,
    vfd.value
FROM
   vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc
   INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data as vfd
         ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd.log_id
WHERE
   vfd.form_id IN (2,3);
```

(fyi: your second image link is the same as the first :))

Comment: Hi, returned: #1054 - Unknown column 'vfd.value' in 'field list'

Comment: Could you upload the 2nd table image view? The links you provided are identical. Which field from the 2nd table are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Try again. I've changed the link between the two tables. It now checks if the purchaseid is the same as the id in the other table. Does this sound correct, or should it be prodid? Or is there any other missing link between the 2 tables :)?

Comment: there's only one common column which is 'id' - could that be half the problem - i think I updated the second table image??!!

Comment: What field in `vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents` should be the same as in `vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data`? Anyways, i changed the query again... Try it :)

Comment: Ha! I can't, though - I'll be playing with this new toy for hours now you've fixed it!  Again, thanks.